# How to call methods of a nested interface

Tags: java, interface

I have an Interface `IOuter` and a nested interface `IInner`. Like

```
interface IOuter {
   public void outerA();
   interface IInner {
      public void innerA();
   }
}
```

Both `IOuter` and `IInner` are having some setter API's.
I made nested interface because the setter API's are valid only for the inner interface.
Both outer and inner interface are implemented in a single class which is not exposed to outside world.

Outside application is interacting with our code through the interface `IOuter`. Now the problem is since they don't have the object of nested interface they are not able to call the nested interface API's.
I don't want to move nested interface API's to outer interface as it might be misunderstood.

Comment: I think the question is miss-understood or i didn't asked it properly. Both the Interface is already implemented inside our code. Outside Application is not creating the object directly is used. Its getting it from someone. So it's aware of only the Interface. Now if application need to call an API of nested interface it needs it object. To make it work i have exposed an API to get nested interface object. Which i am not sure is a right way of coding. So is there any other way of doing it other then exposing and API to get nested interface object.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement both the `IOuter` and the `IInner` interfaces. For example:

```
public class Test implements IOuter, IOuter.IInner {
    @Override
    public void outerA() {

    }

    @Override
    public void innerA() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call nested interface method directly, as shown below

try

```
public class Test implements IOuter, IOuter.IInner  {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test t1 = new Test();
        t1.innerA();        
    }

    public void outerA(){       
    }
    public void innerA(){       
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. Your `innerA()` implementation doesn't override the method definition in the nested interface. Use the `@Override` annotation for proof

Comment: The `innerA` method in your `Test` is not overriding the `innerA()` of the `IInner` interface. Its just some method in your class, with that same name.

Comment: @kocko and R.J  Thanks for pointing out the mistake, updated  the code

Comment: You updated the code, I removed the downvote. Please test your code in some environment, before posting. It's easy to avoid mistakes. :)

Comment: yeah, I should have tested before posting Thanks

Comment: Downvote revoked. Do test your before posting to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

Inner interface can use as a static member of outer or directly as shown below:
Here A is implementation of both outer and inner interfaces.

```
       IOuter o = new A();
        o.outer();

        IOuter.IInner i = new A();
        i.inner();

        //OR 
        IInner i2 = new A();
        i.inner();
```